# Issues rendering React state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am using React Hooks and am having issues rendering my state. So, my state looks like below;

```
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ id: 0, taskName: "", timeField: 0 });
```

In my reducer, I have

```
const initialState = {
  tasks: []
};

const tasksR = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SAVE_TASK": {
      //return [...state, action.payload];
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload]
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

However, I am unable to render the state on the UI.

Also, other question, I have is, for the initial state, is it fine if we just set in the reducer ?
I have seen it also passed/set in createStore() as below;

```
const defaultState = { tasks: [] };
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  defaultState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
window.store = store;
```

Not sute why is the default state also set in this place apart from the reducer ?

My full code example is located at
https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-tp7pv

Comment: you should store `timerId` in a `ref`, otherwise the timer id gets lost between rerenders.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your store looks like this :

```
{
  tasks: {
    tasks: []
  }
}
```

That's why the code inside `if (Array.isArray(props.tasks)) {` is never executed because `props.tasks` (which is the same as `state.tasks`) is an object.

You can get the array of tasks using `props.tasks.tasks` or you can update your store like this :

```
const initialState = [];

const tasksR = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SAVE_TASK": {
      return [...state, action.payload];
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({tasks: tasksR});
```

Comment: Hey...thanks a lot...tried updating in the reducer...however, now seeing this error....Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: You need to iterate state.tasks.tasks not state.tasks. ...state.tasks.tasks

Comment: Sorry...I had to update this as well to const initialState = [];
Seems to be working now

Comment: My question is - Is it true that the "overall state" is still an object actually, but const initialState = [] just corresponds to a sub-state....and all individual reducers combine ultimately to give us the "overall state" ....Would that be correct ?

Comment: that's exactly what `combineReducers` does. It actually combine all your individual reducers into a global one. `cont initialState = []` is actually the initial state of the `tasks` subState

Comment: Awesome...thanks for that...Just one last question which I had added in my original question....where defaultState is passed to createStore()....Why is that needed & how is it different from the initialState we have in the reducer ?

Comment: the defaultState also called `preloadedState` in the documentation https://redux.js.org/api/createstore#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer is an optional parameter. It's usefull if you want to initialize your store with an object built at server side for example. Note that the shape of the state object must match the shape you describe with your reducers